# Calculate $\arctan x$ if $\arcsin x$ is known?

Tags: trigonometry

I haven't been able to figure out using conventional identities, to calculate another if one is known. Say $\arcsin x$ is known, what is $\arctan x$ in terms of the former term?

This is not as easy as it looks.

How do I use the laws of trigonometry to solve this deceptively simple problem?

Comment: Is this in full generality, or is there a specific value that arcsine is to take?

Comment: in general, like we know sinx we can calculate tanx from the laws of trigonometry. Here its the inverse @AlfredYerger

Comment: http://imgur.com/Bd7ugSi I don't know how I'd *do* it, but here's a visual aid.  you have $\alpha$, and need $\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bit of a cheat!!  $tan^{-1}(x)$=$tan^{-1}(sin(sin^{-1}x))$

The only other thing that comes to mind is something similar to $sin^{-1}(x)+cos^{-1}(x)=\pi/2$

A quick look on Wolfram Alpha suggests many formulae but none explicitly use $sin^{-1}(x)$ so I suppose there is no answer to your question. But it's an interesting question.

Comment: You're using $\arctan$ to define $\arctan$.

Comment: @Mariuslp The question wasn't to define $\arctan$, it was to compute $\arctan{x}$ given $\arcsin{x}$. Technically, this fits the question.

Comment: Still. Computing $\arctan$ by using $\arctan$ is not very interesting.

Comment: I agree, it's a feeble way to do it but it'll work.

Comment: I started to try out a few things like using area to transfer between them, and they all came back to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $\sin(\arctan(x))) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Therefore, $\arctan(x) = \arcsin(\sin(\arctan(x)) = \arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})$.

Edit: I just realized that I'm not using $\arcsin(x)$, but another value, so technically this answer is not very relevant.

Comment: shall i set a bounty on that question @Mariuslp

Comment: If you really want an expression using $\arcsin x$, you can remark that $x = \sin(\arcsin x)$. Hence my formula becomes $\arctan(x) = \arcsin(\frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\sqrt{1 + (\sin(\arcsin(x))^2}})$, but it also looks like a cheat: you're still using $\arcsin$ in exactly the same way.

Comment: However, I don't know whether there are better solutions than @Susan's or mine, trigonometry allows little liberty when playing with the functions. At the end you are the one who should decide whether this question is worth a bounty or not